# Illegal mix of collations на master-slave

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос (писал кто то до меня), который на мастере выполняется и отлично отрабатывает, но на слейве на нем падает реплика с ошибкой Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '=' on query.

Мастер и слейв идентичны по настройкам (версия 5.6.17), кодировка на обоих UTF8, сравнение в utf8_general_ci. Используемая база данных и таблицы в запросе также в UTF8, utf8_general_ci. В запросе есть переменные, которые сессионно устанавливаются в

```
SET @`date_start`:=_utf8 COLLATE `utf8_general_ci`;
SET @`date_stop`:=_utf8 COLLATE `utf8_general_ci`;
SET @`prevTelephony`:=NULL;
SET @`prevD`:=NULL;
SET @`minT`:=NULL;
SET @`prevT`:=NULL;
```

Сам запрос :

```
INSERT INTO  AT_t_Dscpl_ForeCast_tmp (Id_Telephony, Id_WFM, date_start,Time_Start, Date_Stop, Time_Stop, Id_Actv)  
  SELECT
    sFC.Id_Telephony,
    sFC.Id_WFM,
    sFC.Date_Start,sFC.minT as Time_Start,
    Cast(date(max(CONCAT(sFC.Date_Stop, ' ', sFC.Time_Stop))) as DATE) as Date_Stop,  
    Cast(time(max(CONCAT(sFC.Date_Stop, ' ', sFC.Time_Stop))) as TIME)as Time_Stop,  
    sFC.Id_Actv  
  from
    (SELECT
      distinct fc.Id_Telephony,fc.Id_WFM,  
      case  
        when @prevTelephony is null then @prevTelephony:=fc.Id_Telephony  
        when @prevTelephony != fc.Id_Telephony  
        then (@prevTelephony := fc.Id_Telephony)  
        and (@minT:= null) and (@prevT := NULL)  
      end as vTelephony,  
      fc.date_start,  
      CASE  
      WHEN @prevD is null  THEN @prevD := fc.date_start  
      WHEN @prevD != fc.date_start  THEN (@minT:= null) and (@prevT := NULL)  
      END nDayStrt,  
      fc.Time_Start,  
      case  
      when @minT is null then @minT:=fc.Time_Start  
      else @minT:=if(@prevT=fc.Time_Start, @minT, fc.Time_Start)  
      end minT,  
      fc.Date_Stop,  
      fc.Time_Stop,  
      if(fc.Id_Actv, 1, 0) as Id_Actv,  
      @prevT := fc.Time_Stop,  
      @prevD := fc.date_start  
    from
      (SELECT
        Id_WFM, Id_Telephony, Date_Start, Time_Start, Date_Stop,Time_Stop,Id_Actv  
      from
        AT_t_Dscpl_ForeCast  
      where
        Date_Start BETWEEN @date_start and
        @date_stop and
        Id_Actv != 99 and
        Id_Telephony != 0) AS fc  
WHERE
  fc.Date_Start BETWEEN @date_start and @date_stop  
order BY  
  fc.Id_Telephony,  
  fc.Id_WFM,  
  fc.date_start,  
  fc.Time_Start) sFC  
group by  
  sFC.Id_Telephony,  
  sFC.Id_WFM,  
  sFC.Date_Start,  
  sFC.minT
```

Comment: Если не сложно, приложите my.cnf обоих серверов. Устанавливается ли кодировка на уровне сервера?

Comment: Конфиги тут  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WsNyT_5QI8bFFCZk5RbGh3UGM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Кодировка на уровне сервера стоит utf8

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте на слейв-сервере кодировку на уровне таблице и столбцов. Чудес не бывает у вас сравнение utf8 с latin1-значением. Возможно на этапе сетапа слейв-сервера была допущена ошибка и таблицы, а вслед за ними и столбцы, получили кодировку latin1, вместо utf8.

Сейчас самым верным будет обратиться к slave-серверу и выполнить для реплицируемой базы данных оператор `SHOW CREATE TABLE` для каждой из таблиц базы данных. Отчет оператора даст используемую кодировку. Если она latin1, нужно пересетапить слейв-сервер, развернув корректный дамп.

Найдите my.cnf обоих серверов и проверьте содержимое директив `character-set-server`, если ее нет, лучше явно установить в utf8. Сейчас это уже не поможет, но не позволит повториться ситуации в будущем.

Как вариант укажите сопоставление явно в запросе

```
WHERE
  Date_Start BETWEEN @date_start AND
  @date_stop AND
  Id_Actv != 99 COLLATE utf8_general_ci AND
  Id_Telephony != 0 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: Я уже смотрел , на уровне таблицы CHARSET=utf8. На уровне столбцов...по ним тип данных int и date.

Comment: А насколько я знаю кодировку на уровне столбцов можно ставить только для char,varchar и text.

Comment: @РоманМороховец Строго говоря да, но у вас в сообщении об ошибке (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) - т.е. MySQL связывает сопоставление с числовым значением, нужно вычислить откуда тут latin1, а лучше задать по умолчанию для всего сервера utf8 на уровне my.cnf

Comment: в my.cnf на мастере и слейве стоит utf8. <<нужно вычислить откуда тут latin1>>__та вот пытаюсь уже неделю как (

Comment: @РоманМороховец, дополнил ответ.

Comment: рассматривал этот вариант, но разработчики не очень хотят менять что то в коде), но видимо таки придеться. Отпишусь позже, помогло или нет.

Comment: @РоманМороховец вообще с select ... insert можно круто нарваться при репликации - в различных версиях MySQL не мало ошибок, которые разламывают репликацию именно на select ... insert. Возможно придется выпиливать такие запросы. Это я к тому, что с таким запросом возможны и другие типы ошибок - на мастере все прокатывает, а репликация ломается.

Comment: хм...спасибо, учту.

Comment: Помогло принудительное указание кодировки в условии where...COLLATE utf8_general_ci . Спасибо за помощь! Эта проблема не поверите тянулась два года, до меня ей никто не заморачивался, скипали и все).